# actions without an explicit type property

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-thunk

As you can see [on this line](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/src/createStore.js#L138) of the Redux source code, actions must have a `type` property. In the [real world](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/real-world) example in the source code repository, there is an action like this, with no `type` property declared.

```
function fetchUser(login) { 
10   return { 
11     [CALL_API]: { 
12       types: [ USER_REQUEST, USER_SUCCESS, USER_FAILURE ], 
13       endpoint: `users/${login}`, 
14       schema: Schemas.USER 
15     } 
16   } 
17 }
```

The `CALL_API` referred to is a JavaScript symbol[here](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/real-world/middleware/api.js#L79)

```
export const CALL_API = Symbol('Call API')
```

On a sidenote, from the Mozilla site, it appears that you access a symbol with array brackets

```
var sym = Symbol("foo");
var obj = {[sym]: 1};
```

So, back to the redux code, the middleware that handles the action without the explicit type seems to access the property created by the CALL_API...

```
export default store => next => action => { 
84   const callAPI = action[CALL_API] 
85   if (typeof callAPI === 'undefined') { 
86     return next(action) 
87   }  function fetchUser(login) { 
10   return { 
11     [CALL_API]: { 
12       types: [ USER_REQUEST, USER_SUCCESS, USER_FAILURE ], 
13       endpoint: `users/${login}`, 
14       schema: Schemas.USER 
15     } 
16   } 
17 }
```

Going back to the first code cited above, if I remove the array brackets from around the call api like this

```
 function fetchUser(login) { 
    10   return { 
    11     CALL_API: {
```

I get the error, "Actions may not have an undefined "type" property".

Question: how does the (correct) use of the symbol in the fetchUser function, for example, satisfy the requirement for a type property on the action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using brackets in an object literal is part of the newer ES6 syntax.  It lets you define a key in an object using an expression, which could include the value of a variable:

```
const keyName = "test";
const obj = { [keyName + "Key"] : 42};
// result: { "testKey" : 42}
```

Symbols can also be used as object keys (see http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/metaprogramming-in-es6-symbols/ ) for some explanation.

When you put the brackets around `[CALL_API]`, you're saying "use the *value* of the `CALL_API` variable as the key".  When you *don't* use brackets, you're saying "Use the literal string `"CALL_API"` as the key name".

The middleware is then looking for an action object which has a key correctly matching the CALL_API symbol.  When it sees one, it stops it, and does *not* pass it onwards to the reducers.  So, when you remove the brackets, you're instead dispatching an action that looks like `{"CALL_API" : {} }`.  That doesn't match what the middleware is looking for, it *does* reach the reducers, and then the type check fails.